# Remote desktop from Windows to Ubuntu

Tags: windows, vnc, remote-access

The only monitor I have is one of those crt huge dinosaurs. I want to access my ubuntu machine from my windows laptop. I have tried a few VNC programs already and I cant get it to work. Any tips?

Or is there a way I can control my Ubuntu machine from my laptop physically, like using a cord or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

If you have configure vnc, remote desktop perfectly then make sure that it is allowed via firewall.

Check your router configuration , make sure that RDP is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial is as about straight forward as they get. Follow this guide [HERE](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/remote-windows-linux.html)

Its a few years old but the principle still applies.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to recommend you just use a X server on your windows box and connect using it. [This post](http://blog.jamesrhall.com/2012/06/ubuntu-1204-and-xdmcp.html) should work for you. Keep in mind that a lot of things in Linux are client server, including the GUI. So your Linux box can do all the work and your windows box can just be a dumb terminal.

I have had pretty good luck with [xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/) in the past.

Comment: Anyone interested bear in mind that forwarding X is a lot slower than VNC over the internet - only really an option in local networks

Answer (score 1):

```
vnc4server -geometry 1024x768 -depth 24
New 'kvmsrv1:7 (root)' desktop is kvmsrv1:7
Starting applications specified in /root/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /root/.vnc/kvmsrv1:7.log
kvmsrv1:7
```

Use this instead of IP. If you set up a password, then give that password. Otherwise, create a password using `vnc4passwd`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're connected to internet then you can use Chrome Remote Desktop Plugin. Its simple and easy to use and will work cross platform.

[image: Chrome Remote Desktop]