# Remote Desktop to Ubuntu from Windows

Tags: gnome, vnc

I am newbie to these forums. Please correct me if I do any mistake.

I have installed Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS version. I want to connect to GNOME Desktop Environment. I have gone through many tutorials but all failed. Although, I was able to connect to desktop using LXDE but requirement is GNOME.

The most successful tutorial I have gone through was:
https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/remote-desktop/install-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04/.

I can see the desktop folder but I can't see the whole Gnome environment with applications etc.

[Ubuntu: During remote desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCl62.png)

Note: I have gone through all the questions on askubuntu.com but no good.
E.g: [Remote desktop from Windows to Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230115/remote-desktop-from-windows-to-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

VNC is what you're looking for. The official Ubuntu wiki has some loose guides on setting this up.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers

Comment: Let me work on it. I'll share the details soon.

Answer (score 0):

TeamViewer is the tool I use to connect from linux to my windows, but it works the other way around too. If you don't use it commercially, it's free :)